# Cannot boot Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu (Windows OS is still there, Ubuntu is on separate partition)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my 64 bit system.  I already had separate partitions for Windows 10 and another one with an older Linux version installed, so I just deleted the Linux partition and created a new one the same size.  Installed Ubuntu using the installer, no issues.  However, I needed to boot back into Windows, which returned "The boot configuration files cannot be found".  Booted back into Ubuntu and checked my hard drive, Windows and all my stuff is still there, didn't touch the other partition at all, but messed up something related to booting.  Here's what I've tried:

- Used the Windows recovery disc (Windows 8 one, I updated to 10 from that) to access cmd.  Then I followed various online tutorials, did bootrec /fixmbr and bootrec /fixboot with no errors, but bcdboot C:\Windows returned "Failed when attempting to copy boot files"
- Got back onto Ubuntu, used the boot-repair utility to attempt to fix the issue.  Was able to use update-grub, which detected two (not sure why it's two but either way) Windows installations.  Boot repair completed, and on startup two Windows installations were listed in the grub menu.  However, neither of them worked, same problem as before.

Willing to provide any log files or information necessary, just didn't know what was needed.  And I would prefer to avoid reinstalling either OS if possible, all the Windows files are still there, I think it's just a booting issue...Thank you to anyone willing to help

Comment: Can you please run Boot Repair again (do not apply any fix) and post the report? Regarding the fixes you tried from Windows: Don't! It's outdated information only applicable to older versions and BIOS/MBR.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Here's the report generated: http://paste2.org/YxHfYU6t - thank you for the reply

Comment: Looks like the boot flag is on the wrong partition, I think sda2 should have it, not sda1.

Comment: Other than that everything looks fine (for a BIOS/MBR installation).

Comment: @ubfan1 I switched the boot flag from sda1 to sda2, still doesn't work properly unfortunately :( I'm doing boot repair again because I'm not sure what else to do.  But I noticed this screen, mentions sda and sda6 but nothing else - is this normal, or an issue?  Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about: http://i.imgur.com/PB1ocgi.png?1

Comment: @CelticWarrior Oddly enough, it still isn't working after changing the boot flag like the other commenter suggested.  Although I did see something I'm wondering about, see my other comment

Comment: looks like you also have grub installed on the sda6 partition, and oddly the MBR grub seems to refer to that.  Maybe just reinstall grub to sda (and fix the boot flag on sda2).

Comment: @ubfan1 Should there be an option to install it on sda2?  Or should it be fine?  Just did another reinstall of grub, it detects Windows doing an update-grub and adds them to the list, and I've added the boot flag to sda2.  But I still receive the same error as before about missing boot configuration files...

Comment: Your reinstall of grub should have been to /dev/sda, not the partition sda1.  When you fix the sda install, it should find its config files.